# Use Datalist to display list of teacher and subjects they can teach in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have a question like this:
In database I have two tables:

`Teacher {TeacherID, TeacherName}` and 

`Teacher_Subject {TeacherID, SubjectName}`

So I used datalist to display list of teacher in database with format like this:

`TeacherID: Label1 Eval("TeacherID")`

`TeacherName: Label2 Eval("TeacherName")`

Subject(s) can teach: ?

One teacher can teaches many subjects and i want to display those subjects but i dont know how to bind those subjects. I also don't know what we called these kind of problems so if you can please give me a general name for these kind of problems for future references.Thank you.

Comment: Firstly you have to figure out how to fetch those subjects. Then use GOOGLE to search on databinding using asp.net

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Rap god, I did know how to get those subject but I dont know how to bind multiple value, for example Label1 Eval("TeacherID") is ok because it's 1 on 1, but for Subject it's many on 1 so I dont know how.

Comment: may this idea will help to construct your view for your Scenario. In your DataList take one Item Template of Checkbox list. Fetch data from table Teacher_Subject. OnItemDataBound event you could check the Chekboxes that have same subject name listing on fetched data.

Answer (score 0):

On the aspx side, a DataList looks like this:

```
   <asp:DataList
   ID="SUBJECTLIST"    CellPadding="10" RepeatDirection="Vertical"  RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatColumns="2" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>   
     <%--%>             
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

You can style it like you want, this one for example will accomodate on 2 columns. The datalist has inside an item template.  Inside you put the item you want to repeat.  If it's just information, a label will do just fine. This is how it should look.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("XYZ") %>' ID="lbXYZ"></asp:Label>
```

You must remember what you put inside Bind's. You can bind the Text, or the ID, among other properties.  Here will be just Text.

Now on the .cs file. You create a DataTable, you add a column called XYZ (what you put inside Bind), of type string. Then you add rows foreach subject, and finally you bind SUBJECTLIST with its DataSource = the datatable you created, and then call `DataBind();`